# ssh keys authentication for TFVC

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, devops, ssh-keys, tfvc

I am working on a Visual Studio 2019 community project.

I have set up a remote git repository on azure-devops.

I can push/pull commits by command line. Everything works fine: it does not ask me any password because i have put my ssh public key in azure devops.

I have created a second project but I need to work with TFVC instead of git.

My ssh key is still configured but visual studio asks my Microsoft Login/pass instead of using ssh key. How can I tell visual studio to use my ssh key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. TFVC does not support SSH auth. In Azure DevOps you can only use OAuth authentication.

SSH was added specifically for Git and by the time that was added, TFVC was already a "finished product".